# Do I need to install ssl certificate on all webserver which are behind Load Balancer on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have web servers with auto-scaling enable behind my Load Balancer. And I want the communication between Load Balancer and web server to be https(ssl). To do this, do I need to install ssl certificate on all server?

I have already installed ssl certificate on Load Balancer. But I need the communication between Load Balancer and webserver to be https(ssl). I am using AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would have to install an SSL certificate on every web server, in order to enable SSL communication between the load balancer and each of those web servers.